# Why is my Dynamic Array of Char's still returning uninitialized values?

Tags: c++, variables, pointers

For some weird reason, it keeps on creating uninitilized values when I pass in the length as 12, it creates an array of about 16 and stores the rest with crap that I don't want. Anyone know why this isn't working? It's for an assignment that's due tomorrow and this is my last problem... Any help would be appreciated thanks.

```
char * convertToUppercase (char* toUpSize, int length) {
    std::cout << "ToUpsize: " << toUpSize << "\nLength: " << length << "\n";
    char * upsized = new char[length];
    for (int i = 0; toUpSize[i]; i++) {
        upsized[i] = toupper(toUpSize[i]);
    }
    return upsized;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "creating uninitialized values"?

Comment: How do call this function? What args do you pass?

Comment: From what I believe, it shows all these funny symbols. Like this one: http://bit.ly/pjus7L

Comment: Allocating and returning array of char inside a helper function like that smells of a bad design and possible memory leaks (i.e. are you sure you will always remember to delete returned arrray?). You should either return std::string (C++ style) or add another char * argument - destination array (C style).

Comment: It's basically capitalizing a string, it takes a pointer to an array of char's and the length of the character to upsize. The only reason I added the length as an arg was to see if it would function correctly, as in, the correct amount of values but yet again it doesn't.

Comment: Where is the C++ part of this? Can't see any use of std::string.

Comment: Yet again, gwia, the only reason I did that was to see if it would function correctly from my original problem which is in the image I posted above (the bit.ly) one. If there is a better method, please feel free to share.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use std::string because of the assignment. I must use C style strings in my C++ program.

Comment: I psoted the fix to the comment you posted on Nawaz's answer containing more code. But you deleted the comment, so I deleted my fix.

Comment: @Brandon: Here's the beef. Every C style string you allocate should have a null terminator, and every C style string you allocate should have space allocated for the null terminator. Do both of those and your code will be correct.

Comment: I'm sorry John... I was trying to post it with code but I'm not sure how to in these comments like things... I am trying with that but as mentioned earlier, storing on the heap can cause a problem. So, is there anyway to program this function without using the heap?

Comment: @Brandon: That is **THE** drawback of using C style strings. To do anything meaningful you almost always end up using dynamic memory allocation, or restricting yourself to fixed length strings. The requirements that you must do this with C style strings is bonkers (I realise that it's not your choice). BTW, use backticks for code in comments.

Answer (score 3):

I think you either write `i< length`  in the for loop, instead of `toUpSize[i]` as:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    upsized[i] = toupper(toUpSize[i]);
 }
```

Or pass `toUpSize` as null-terminated string if you want to write `toUpSize[i]` in the `for` loop condition. If you do so, then you've to put `\0` at the end of `upsized` after you exit from the loop, at index `i` for which `toUpSize[i]` is `\0`. And to accomplish this, you've te move the definition of `i` outside the `for` loop, so that you can use it after you exit from the loop.

Null-terminated string is what which has `\0` character at the end of the string.

```
char x[]  = {'N', 'a', 'w', 'a', 'z' };
char y[]  = {'N', 'a', 'w', 'a', 'z', '\0' };
```

Here, `x` is *not* a null-terminated string, but `y` is a null-teminated string.

If the strings are defined as:

```
char z[] = "Nawaz";
const char *s = "Nawaz";
```

Here `z` and `s` are null-terminated string, because both of them are created out of "Nawaz" which is a null-terminated string. Note that `sizeof("Nawaz")` would return `6`, not `5`, precisely because there is an `\0` at the end of the string.

Comment: Just a question, how do I post code in this comment thing? I will show a little bit more but I made the last value of upsized to be '\0'. When I am debugging using VC++, upsized is actually initilized as: 0x005a16c8 "ÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍýýýý««««««««" char *

Comment: @Brandon: How do you which is last? Why don't you post more code in your question itself?

Comment: I would post from where the function is called but as I mentioned, since it is an assignment, I don't really want to share it all but... How I get the length value is:

Comment: int ptLength = strlen(plaintext);
 int kLength = strlen(key);
    plaintext = convertToUppercase(plaintext, ptLength);
    key = convertToUppercase(key, kLength);

Comment: So why do you calculate the length outside of the convertToUppercase function when you actually need the length inside the convertToUppercase function. Doesn't that make your problem harder? You've been told the answers by several people, you need a null terminator and you need to allocate space for a null terminator. Fix both those problems and everything will work.

Comment: Okay, that's all working well and fine now, thanks for your help everyone. I have another problem though... Is there anyway I can write this without using heap memory? Because when I try to allocate an array of char's with a variable, it won't let me because it needs to be a 'constant value' so I use heap memory. The only thing is, I can't actually delete upsized outside of this function. Is there anyway I can either delete it outside this function or write it without dynamic memory?

Comment: @Brandon: No. Even if there were a way to allocate a dynamic array on the stack (which is actually possible in C99, but not in C++), there would be no way to return such a beast, because the return type of a function cannot be an array. What you *could* do is return nothing and instead pass a pointer to an array that is already big enough: `void to_upper_case(const char* src, int length, char* dst)`.

Comment: @Brandon: What do you mean you can't delete it? Simply write `char* p = convertToUppercase(some_text, some_length); /* use p */ ; delete[] p;` Note that the `[]` after `delete` are required for deleting arrays. `delete p;` without the `[]` will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Ah yes, I know I can delete them I just couldn't access the variables outside that function that I had defined them in. I followed what you said how get it to return nothing and pass a pointer in to an array that is already big enough. That's all well and fine, should work, but it's saying that convertToUppercase must return a value? Also, how do I add code into my comments?

Another edit: It was my own fault for not removing the * after the void sorry :) That's fixed but for some reason, I'm still getting heap errors so I'm looking into it now.

Comment: Okay, I have figured out why I have heap errors. I believe that the pointers I am being using as arguments are still used, do I have to set them to NULL before I delete them or not?

Comment: Setting a pointer to NULL *before* deleting would be completely pointless (and after is considered an anti-pattern). Please update your question to include the new code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to null-terminate the returned array if you want to print it like a string. Make sure that it ends with a null-terminator. Depending on how you calculate the `length` argument you may need to add extra space for it to the array. You may also want to make sure that the array that you pass in is null-terminated.

Comment: Sorry to sound stupid but how do you get it to "NULL terminate"? EDIT: Also, looking at it now... Will I have to make the length of upsized length + 1 to allow room for the "\0"?

Comment: You can set the first element after the string to zero. The length of the array has to be the length of the string plus one for the terminator.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the termination char:

```
char * convertToUppercase (char* toUpSize, int length) {
   std::cout << "ToUpsize: " << toUpSize << "\nLength: " << length << "\n";
   char * upsized = new char[length];
   int i;
   for (i = 0; toUpSize[i]; i++) { // stops when you get toUpSize[i]==0
       upsized[i] = toupper(toUpSize[i]);
   }
   upsized[i] = '\0'; //add termination
   return upsized;
}
```

Your code assumes `length` to be the length of the allocated array, not the *length* of the string. `strlen(toUpSize)` counts the chars that are not '\0' from position 0 in toUpSize.

E.g.: strlen("abc\0def") -> 3
      sizeof("abc\0def") -> 8!

Comment: It seems to be working at the moment :) Thanks for that mate, greatly appreciate your help and same with the post below.

Comment: There is no room for the NUL terminator, hence `upsized[i] = '\0'` is a buffer overflow.

Comment: I've actually made room for the NUL terminator now and the function is working correctly, thankfully but now I have a new problem with the dynamic memory. If you read my latest comment on my first post, any chance you can help?

Comment: Sorry, it's actually on the post below, here is the question though: "Okay, that's all working well and fine now, thanks for your help everyone. I have another problem though... Is there anyway I can write this without using heap memory? Because when I try to allocate an array of char's with a variable, it won't let me because it needs to be a 'constant value' so I use heap memory. The only thing is, I can't actually delete upsized outside of this function. Is there anyway I can either delete it outside this function or write it without dynamic memory?"

Comment: There's room for the null terminator as length is not the strlen. Otherwise just loop to length. The whole point of looping till the termination string is the avoid copying unnecessary chars.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you even bothering with char pointers? This is C++, not C.

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

std::string to_upper_case(std::string str)
{
    std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), toupper);
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << to_upper_case("hello world\n");
}
```

If you decide to stick to the C solution, reserve one more char for the NUL terminator and put it there:

```
char * upsized = new char[length + 1];   // note the +1
upsized[length] = 0;
```

Comment: If it wasn't an assignment, I would. But unfortunately I have to use C Style Strings.